# Emacs -- inhibit redisplay until post-command-hook finishes

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to inhibit redisplay of the current buffer until the `post-command-hook` finishes?  If so, an example would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE:  It will be necessary to calculate points and columns based upon the characters being inserted or deleted, so the freeze should only be visually -- however, the buffer should still be accessible for modification and calculations.

Goal:

- Step Number 1:  `inhibit-redisplay` -- i.e., visually freeze the buffer.
- Step Number 2:  `pre-command-hook` -- delete overlays.
- Step Number 3:  `self-insert-command` -- add or delete a character.
- Step Number 4:  `post-command-hook` -- add new overlays.
- Step Number 5:  Visually unfreeze the buffer and redisplay the new configuration.

Comment: Does `(elisp) Forcing Redisplay` help? (`redisplay-dont-pause` set to `nil` sounds relevant).

Comment: @phils -- thank you for teaching me about a new variable.  Between what you mentioned and what Stefan mentioned, I am pointed in the right direction.  I'm going to keep working on it . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the normal behavior.

Comment: Thank you -- then, I must be altering the normal behavior somewhere in my code.  I'll work on it some more to see if I can track it down.

Comment: Redisplay can take place "in the middle of a command" if you call something like `sit-for`, `read-key`, `accept-process-input` or things like that.

Comment: I was finally able to obtain the visual affect desired by running my custom functions off of the `post-command-hook`.  However, there appears to be a built-in `redisplay` occurring somewhere between executing the `pre-command-hook` and any function that *subsequently* manually moves `point` in the buffer -- e.g., arrow keys or adding / removing text in the buffer.  In the context of my question above, I believe that there is a redisplay that necessarily occurs during/after Step 2 or during/after Step 3.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what it is that you see (and that you don't like) we can help better.

Comment: I found it!!!!!  :) :) :)  -- there was one of these `(redisplay t)` in another of my `post-command-hook` functions that *preceded* my overlay function (also within that same `post-command-hook`).   So, a redisplay was being forced after `self-insert-command` and *before* my overlay function had a chance to finish doing its job.  Thank you for helping me to understand that I was overriding the default behavior.